# C# .NET Dependency Injection Order Clarification

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I do not get the behaviour of DI in the following case.

```
internal class Program
{   
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        
        services.AddLogging(configure =>
        {
            configure.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            configure.AddConsole();
        });

        services.ConfigureAndInjectServices(configuration);

        using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation($"serviceBusFqns: ....");
        logger.LogInformation($"serviceBusFqns: ....");    
    }       
}

public static class DependencyInjectionHelper
{
    public static void ConfigureAndInjectServices(
        this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        var fqns = config.GetValue<string>("ServiceBus:FullyQualifiedNs");
        var id = config.GetValue<string>("ServiceBus:ManagedIdentityClientID");

        services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace(fqns);
            builder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        });
    }
}
```

I am able to see the logs produced on Console. But if I swap the order of these lines:

```
services.ConfigureAndInjectServices(configuration);

services.AddLogging(configure =>
{
    configure.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    configure.AddConsole();
});
```

the log does not log anymore (to Console). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this happens due to the following:

[`AddAzureClientsCore`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/10e43c2575616ec9e774f623bf1f91b195fe52d6/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/src/AzureClientServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L65) which is invoked by `AddAzureClients` tries to register `NullLoggerFactory` as `ILoggerFactory`:

```
collection.TryAddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();
```

While `AddLogging` will [try to add `LoggerFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9d56a4c11853b3b5bb1eca5f1102a351d90607bf/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38) as one:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
```

`TryAdd{...}` methods will add the registration only if the service type hasn't already been registered so the first one called wins (unlike with the `Add{...}` methods which will result in the last one wins).

Comment: To me, this seems a design flaw in the Azure library. It probably shouldn't have tried to add a NullLoggerFactory, but rather either forward the call to `.AddLogging`, or don't try to add logging at all, and leave that to the client. But both options are likely breaking changes.